# Telegram send message with clickable bot command

Tags: api, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm writing a bot in telegram (using c#).

I want the bot to send message to a user with a list of clickable links. When user presses such a link, the client should post this command back to the bot. It should look like this (example from @pollbot):
[image]

I tried:

1. sendMesage method with parse_mode=HTML and tg:\ links. Problem:
   telegram renders them as unsafe and navigates away from the chat. Or shows no link.

   ```
   /sendMessage?chat_id=xxxxxxxx&parse_mode=HTML&text=<a href="\Command">CommandText</a>
   ```

   etc...
2. sendMessage with markdown  - same result or no link

   ```
   /sendMessage?chat_id=xxxxxxxxx&parse_mode=markdown&text=[\CommandText](\Command)
   ```
3. inline keyboard works OK, but I need a link, not a button

Any advice on how to implement this is higly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Words starting with a "/" in a text are automatically made clickable as a link. You can just use `sendMessage` without a `parse_mode` and send the text `/newpoll`.

Comment: How about active hyperlink with tg command? Like `[text](/command)` with clickable "text" ? Is there a way to do this magic?

Comment: @noobsaibot nope, either use inline buttons or explicit `/command` in text. It seems that there's no third way :(